# Cannot find any Android targets in this SDK in IntelliJ 2016

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I get this error when I want to add android sdk to intellij 2016:

**`Cannot find any Android targets in this SDK`**

What I did:

1. Download and install Java JDK-8
2. Download Android SDK by installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe (144MB) and install it (Revision 24.4.1)
3. Open SDK Manager to download and install packages
4. Download and install IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate (version 2016.1.1)
5. Run IntelliJ
6. Open configuration -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure
7. Add jdk location (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91`) in project
   tab
8. Add the android sdk location
   (`C:\Users\hosein\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`) in project tab

**In the last step I get this error:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solutions for this error message:

- after adding the SDK and download the packages with the SDK Manager
- got the error message: Cannot find any Android Targets in this SDK
- close Intellij
- reopen Intellij
- it worked ..

Comment: Thanks! Restarting IntelliJ helped me.

Comment: Worked for me too

Answer (score 2):

This error message means that IntelliJ didn't find any virtual device to run your project in.

You need to create a new Android Virtual Device (AVD) using the AVD manager tool.

Next time you'll try to create a new project you select the same SDK path as before and IntelliJ will automatically find your newly created AVD.

Comment: Targets are different than AVD's.

Comment: I faced the same problem and I installed the Android 5.1.1 package with all its sub-packages besides the previously installed SDK Tools, SDK platform-tools and the SDK build-tools. Then I tried again and it didn't work, when I finally added a new Android Virtual Device it worked just fine.

Comment: run `android avd` from `android-sdk-linux/tools` to create a new AVD.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:

1) Open configuration -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure

[image]

2) Select *SDKs* under **Platform Settings**

3) Click green plus button and select Android SDK

[image]

4) Enter path to installed Android SDK. In your case it is `C:\Users\hosein\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

5) Select one of platform installed and JDK level and click okay

After doing these steps error 'Cannot find any Android targets in this SDK' does not appear any more.